# Cannot call value of non-function type of UIViewController when using generic types

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to define generic function to access any controller from UITabBarController and return it.

```
protocol TabBarRoutable {
    func select<T: UIViewController>(type: T.Type, from context: UIViewController?) -> T?
}
extension TabBarRoutable {
    func select<T: UIViewController>(type: T.Type, from context: UIViewController?) -> T? {
        return context?.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first(where: { ($0 as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first is T })
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
extension TabBarRoutable {
    func select<T: UIViewController>(type: T.Type, from context: UIViewController?) -> T? {
        return context?.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first(where: { ($0 as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first is T }) as? T
    }
}
```

I think error shown by compiler is bit misleading, real issue is I guess compiler couldnt figure out the return type of the expression

Answer (score 1):

`UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first` is always a `UIViewController`.

Return `UIViewController?` instead of `T?`

```
func select<T: UIViewController>(type: T.Type, from context: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
    
    return context?.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first(where: { ($0 as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first is T})

}
```